# Splitting ESP32 sketch into multiple threads and files

Tags: c++, multithreading, arduino, microcontroller, esp32

I'm working on a quite complex and large sketch for my ESP32 and I'm dividing it into threads and classes, splitting everything in different files. For sake of simplicity I'm gonna show you just the idea of my project setup.

For instance, I'm using a BME280 sensor to read temperature, humidity, and pressure values. Therefore, I created an header file called `bme280.h` and an associated cpp file called `bme280.cpp`. Here's the content of the two files.

**bme280.h**

```
#ifndef BME280_H
#define BME280_H

#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>

#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)

typedef struct {
  float temperature;
  float pressure;
  float humidity;
}bmeData;

class BME280_sensor {  
  public:
    BME280_sensor();
    bmeData readBmeData();

  private:
    Adafruit_BME280 bme;
};

#endif
```

**bme280.cpp**

```
#include "bme280.h"

BME280_sensor::BME280_sensor() {
  bool status;
  
  status = bme.begin(0x76);  
  if (!status) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("BME280 sensor correctly initialized!");
}

bmeData BME280_sensor::readBmeData() {
  bmeData bmeValues;

  bmeValues.temperature = bme.readTemperature();
  bmeValues.pressure = bme.readPressure() / 100.0F;
  bmeValues.humidity = bme.readHumidity();

  return bmeValues;
}
```

This is basically how I'm using every sensor.

Now, my `.ino` file is busy doing some other job, so I used the `pthread` library for creating a different thread in charge of reading sensors values. Hence, my `.ino` file, before doing its job, starts this thread, which I named `mainThread`. Here's an example:

**file.ino**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "main.h"

void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Serial initialized");

  pthread_t mainThreadRef;
  int mainValue;

  mainValue = pthread_create(&mainThreadRef, NULL, mainThread, (void*)NULL);

  if (mainValue) {
     Serial.println("Main thread error occured");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Some other job
}
```

The main thread, instead, is implemented using a `main.h` file and a `main.cpp` file. Here's an example:

**main.h**

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <Arduino.h>

void *mainThread();

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.h"
#include "bme280.h"

void *mainThread() {
  BME280_sensor bme;
  
  while (1) {
    bmeData bmeValues = bme.readBmeData();
    
    Serial.println(bmeValues.temperature);
    Serial.println(bmeValues.humidity);
    Serial.println(bmeValues.pressure);
    
    delay(3000);
  }
}
```

Now, I wonder if this whole structure of the project is good, because I'm facing weird values reading, like temperature over 100 or pressure under 0, and some other weird stuff. To be more precise:

1. Is it "safe" to have a thread acting as the main thread doing all the jobs?
2. Is it good to have a different class for each sensor that I am using or does it interfere with sensor readings?

Thank you all in advance for you help!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it "safe" to have a thread acting as the main thread doing all the jobs?

Yes. The thing where `setup()` and `loop()` functions get executed is also a thread. It's probably the first thread in the system, but otherwise there's no difference between it and the threads that you yourself create.

The hard part is not running an isolated process in its own thread - that's usually easy, and often a good idea. The hard part is getting data across different threads. I recommend [Mastering the FreeRTOS Real Time Kernel](https://www.freertos.org/Documentation/RTOS_book.html) for reading on how FreeRTOS threads (that's what the ESP32 is really using, pthreads is just a wrapper around it) work and how to communicate between them.

> Is it good to have a different class for each sensor that I am using or does it interfere with sensor readings?

If you have one class per type of sensor which wraps the mundane details of how to talk to that sensor, then this is generally considered good design (encapsulation etc). But it depends, really. The devil is in the details. Note that the Arduino or Adafruit sensor libraries already do that anyway - they tend to provide a nice, simple interface that you can use without knowing the details of how it works. Don't bother wrapping those (unless you have a clear purpose).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a very useful answer, I'll totally check the FreeRTOS book! Regarding creating one class per sensor, I chose to do that because I know that libraries already provide very simple interfaces, but unlike the bme280 sensor, others require longer setup and usage, so I wanted to have my "main" code as clean as possible. I just wonder if this structure of the project could affect sensors readings. So far I'm encountering this problem only with the bme280 sensor.

Comment: Project structure does not cause bugs. Errors made during coding cause bugs :) Or bad wiring, or bad power supply, or whatever.